# Visual Studio 2015 installation on AS or WS server of SPS 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

Folks,

I need to install VS 2015, but not sure if its appropriate to install on AS or WS server of SPS 2013.

Any pointer....

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to install visual studio on production servers.

- it will destabilize the prod environment
- directly development on prod server never ever a good idea.

But on Dev server you can install it n it does not matter which one you pick.

https://m.reddit.com/r/sharepoint/comments/2sqn70/do_we_need_visual_studio_installed_on_sharepoint/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869.aspx

Comment: Thanks Wagas
We dont have a DEV environment and wanna make changes to few pages residing on SPS 2013 production.

Comment: Again it is not recommended and you may end up issues...i would recommend create a VM locally then make changes.i think you dont need SharePoint server rather just dlls.

Comment: wagas,

I`ve network level access from my machine to SPS server.
Is it fine if I install VS 2015 on my client machine and will it allow to connect to the pages hosted on SPS 2013 and perform changes.

Heard for that doesnt works and you need VS 2015 on the Server.
happy to be proved wrong.